# Make specific elements in designMode iframe read-only?

Tags: iframe, designmode

I have an iframe which has designMode set to 'on'. In it, I have a div which the user should be able to type in, and also in the iframe, I have another div which the user should NOT be able to type in.

Is there a way to do this? Using contentEditable is not a solution in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Apply both [`-moz-user-select: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-user-select) and [`-moz-user-modify: read-only`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-user-modify) to the element. There are also `-webkit` equivalents. Remember, designMode doesn't work in Internet Explorer.